# GravatarLocalCache Plugin Broken in WordPress 4.2

Tags: cache, gravatar

Trying to fix a plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravatarlocalcache/ not mine) which broke on the 4.2 update.

The plugin makes a locally cached version of Gravatar.com avatars.

Plugin hasn't been updated recently (current version 1.1.2) and looks abandoned, so though I've posted in the WordPress support forum, doubt I'll get a fix from the plugin author.

Tracked the issue down to WordPress 4.2 (works in 4.1), but don't know why.

The plugin makes a local copy of Gravatar.com avatar images using

```
$_tmp = download_url(str_replace(utf8_encode('&amp;'), '&', $_imageurl));
```

line 211

Github code at https://github.com/oikeusministerio/blogi.otakantaa.fi/blob/master/wp-content/plugins/gravatarlocalcache/GravatarLocalCache.php

With avatars that have a Gravatar account (registered email addresses) the correct image is saved locally. For the randomly generated avatars the default Gravatar logo (blue avatar with a G in the middle) is saved instead with the correct filename.

So for commenters who have a Gravatar account their profile images are saved locally, for generated avatars the correct filename is saved, but it's a copy of the G logo.

Avatar changes in 4.2 is the addition of responsive images using the scrset attribute which is a copy of the Gravatar URL ending in x2. I don't see how this would stop the correct image being saved for the randomly generated images only.

Thanks.

David

Comment: Is there any debugging information about what the values and results of those variables are? This plugin seems a little redundant since the browser can just request ( and cache locally ) gravatars

Comment: Exactly as @TomJNowell said. Why lose all that Gravatar has to offer? (parallel requests, CDN, optimized caching, bandwidth saving yada yada yada)

Comment: I use caching for performance reasons. Explained at http://stallion-theme.co.uk/wordpress-gravatars/
gravatar.com doesn't optimize it's images and has the browser cache set too short (5 minutes) which effectively means the images aren't cached by a browser: caching an image for only 5 minutes means most users will have to download again every visit.

So by using gravatar.com for avatar images the Google PageSpeed Insight Tool throws out a bunch of warnings, since Google considers page speed important SEO wise, not fixing them could have a negative impact on Google rankings.

Comment: The plugin has one PHP warning related to unlink: tries to unlink the tmp file when it's already been unlinked, I think the error trips when the image is downloaded from gravatar.com. Been throwing this error out since day one, so don't think it's related to the 4.2 issue.